# ActiveQuery to array (asArray)

Tags: php, yii2

What's wrong with that query?

```
$numery = Number::find()
        ->select('number.phone_number')
        ->from('number')
        ->leftJoin('ordered_number', ['ordered_number.number_id' => 'number.phone_number'])
        ->where(['ordered_number.order_id' => 123])
        ->asArray();
```

I'm not sure if asArray is used in good way and also if I have to end my query with **one()** or **all()** because all the examples I've seen have it.

I changed it to:

```
        $numery = Number::find()
                ->select('number.phone_number')
                ->from('number, ordered_number')
                ->where(['ordered_number.number_id' => 'number.id'])
                ->andWhere(['ordered_number.order_id' => 123])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
```

But still I get NULL instead of 4-element array. When I delete the "where" part I get all the numbers I have, so I suppose there is a problem somewhere there.
The query that works in raw MySQL and that I want to use looks like this:

```
SELECT number.phone_number 
FROM number, ordered_number 
WHERE ordered_number.number_id=number.id 
AND ordered_number.order_id=123
```

Comment: What do you expect and what happens indeed? What is the exact problem

Comment: it ends in null, even thought it should be 3 or 4 record that match. I suppose I don't really get the syntax of find() method

Comment: null means that no records satisfying your query found. Try `->getRawSql()` instead of `->all()` to get plain SQL query and check whether is matches your expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the **first** one:

```
$numery = Number::find()
    ->select('number.phone_number')
    ->from('number')
    ->leftJoin('ordered_number', ['ordered_number.number_id' => 'number.phone_number'])
    ->where(['ordered_number.order_id' => 123])
    ->asArray();
```

You need to end it with `one()` or `all()` depending on the number of results you are expecting to get.
`one()` gives you single DB row, `all()` gives you array of DB rows.
Without `asArray()` it gives you object (or array of objects in case of `all()`) - with `asArray()` it gives you array (or array of arrays) obviously.

One more thing - when you use `Model::find()` static method you don't have to set `from()` as it will automatically use the underlying DB table for the model.

**Update**: `leftJoin` is wrong - it should be

```
->leftJoin('ordered_number', 'ordered_number.number_id = number.phone_number')
```

About **second** one:

```
$numery = Number::find()
            ->select('number.phone_number')
            ->from('number, ordered_number')
            ->where(['ordered_number.number_id' => 'number.id'])
            ->andWhere(['ordered_number.order_id' => 123])
            ->asArray()
            ->all();
```

You are adding two tables in `from()`. This method states that in that case yu should use array instead of string:

```
->from(['number', 'ordered_number'])
```

Comment: I have:            `$numery = Number::find()
                    ->select('number.phone_number')
                    ->leftJoin('ordered_number', ['ordered_number.number_id' => 'number.id'])
                    ->where(['ordered_number.order_id' => 123])
                    ->asArray()
                    ->all();`
And it is still null. With your advice nothing has changed, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Depends on the fact if there is anything in your database that should be returned when `ordered_number.order_id = 123`

Comment: Yes, there are 4 records that should be displayed. When I use sql query I added at the end of the question, everything goes smoothly, but when I try to do it with Yii it fails.

Comment: @Bizley :I have doubt about the alias `number` he has used, is it correct way?

Comment: @NitinP she used proper table name I guess.

Comment: @Olga try to get the generated SQL first (like SilverFIre said), maybe there is something wrong with it. Just echo the first one with `->rawSql` instead of `->asArray()->all()`

Comment: @Bizley I have nothing like `->rawSql`, `->rawSql()` or `->getRawSql()`. In every case it tells me that it is unknown method.

Comment: @Olga right, use `->createCommand()->rawSql` (property so no `()`)

Comment: @Bizley that helped, I get this:
` SELECT `number`.`phone_number` FROM `number` LEFT JOIN `ordered_number` ON `ordered_number`.`number_id`='number.id' WHERE `ordered_number`.`order_id`=123 `
And MyQSL gives me null on that. I guess there must be en error, but no idea where.

Comment: @Olga maybe left join is not what you want? What about `innerJoin()`?

Comment: @Bizley yes, I'm sure left join is okay. When I delete all ' and ` from rawSql and put it right into my base, it works like I want. The only problem are ' and `, which are added automatically by Yii and I cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `$numery` ends up holding the `ActiveQuery` object created by the `find()` method and modified by the other methods after it.

You need to use the `one()` or `all()` methods at the end so you execute the query and get back the result of the query.

The `asArray()` method just tells the `ActiveQuery` object to return it's result as an Array instead of an Object or Array of Objects.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to:
 
           $numery = Number::find()
                    ->select('number.phone_number')
                    ->from('number, ordered_number')
                    ->where(['ordered_number.number_id' => 'number.id'])
                    ->andWhere(['ordered_number.order_id' => 123])
                    ->asArray()
                    ->all();

But still my result is NULL, instead of 4-element array.